# Volume Scatter goes Black

Tags: rendering, volumetrics

I've followed some tutorials on Volume Scatter material in Cycle like this one : 
http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-atmospheric-lighting-blender/

But I can't go any further because of this :

[image]

This is the render of a Volume Scatter material applied on a simple cube.
Whatever the object, whatever the shape. If I turn on the volume on the complete scene, everything goes black.
CPU or GPU render, it's the same. I tried every single option in the render & material, it does not change anything... I'm out of option.

I was really fancy to use that awesome feature, if someone has a solution, I will be super happy !

Thanks ! 
Happy blending !

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/cycles-node-setup-for-volumetric-shader. See [also this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/how-to-use-the-volume-socket-in-cycles) and [wiki](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/volume.html) for even more info. In general, volume shader should be connected to the *Volume* input socket of the **Material** output node. For now it's connected to the **Diffuse** which is why you get it black.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your cube is black because your volume scatter node is plugged into the *surface* input of the material output node.

From the [manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/volume_scatter.html#volume-scatter) on the shader,

> The Volume Shader output must be plugged into the Volume Input of the [Material](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/output/material.html#inputs) or [World Output](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/output/world.html#inputs) node.

[image]

Comment: @ Timaroberts - This may be offtopic, how do you make those gif on your answer, is it blender's screencast or some other software?

Comment: @hawkenfox read here on how to create them. http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't check the nodes, 
I'm fealing bad it was so dumb |-(